# How do I link which will take me to the page along with filter

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to provide link which will take me to Page 2 along with filter in the column 'Managed_by' applied as 'Internal'

```
   Select 'Open' label,
round(count(*),0) value,
'f?p='||:APP_ID||':2:'||:APP_SESSION||'::2::'||MANAGED_BY||':Internal'
from DATA
```

ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query!

ORA-06550: line 2, column : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Looks like you're missing a column alias, if this post is true to your actual example. I also suspect your second ::2:: needs to jump to the right one place, so it is :::2:

Comment: Inspite of changing my second alias to ':::2:', its not working

Comment: The 2 was a side issue, you were passing that into DEBUG param, not clear cache. Each column needs an alias, your sample does not have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APEX_PAGE.GET_URL` or `APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL` function for build right URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query:

```
Select  'Open' label,
round(count(*),0) value,
CASE WHEN MANAGED_BY = 'internal' then
    '<A HREF="f?P=&APP_ID.:2:&SESSION.::NO:RP,2:P2_internal:'||MANAGED_BY||'">
    </A>'
    ELSE null end as MANAGED_BY_link
From table_name;
```

By this Case statement, if 'internal' data is in MANAGED_BY column, it will create link and on click, it will redirect to page 2 item p2_internal, else link will be disabled.